# OpenCL Memory Access

Tags: c++, c, opencl, nvidia

I am currently working with OpenCL and try to write data to an array which will be used from the CPU afterwards. The local work group size is "1" and the global work group size is the size of the array. 
The problem is the following in kernel.cl:

```
__kernel void foo (..., __global int *a){
 int test_array[2];
 for (int i = 0; i<20; i++){
  ... // do something here 
 }
 test_array[0] = 5;
 int test = test_array[1];

 a[gid] = test; // this throws an error at the graphical unit 
 a[gid] = test_array[0] // but this works if we assign test_array after the for-loop
```

While the error occurs, the screen gets black for a second and returns errorcode "-5" (CL_OUT_OF_RESSOURCES), but this seems to be the Nvidia default errorcode.

The reading to the test_array (int test..) shows that we are able to read it and a[gid]=test_array[0] shows that we are able to access the a[]-array but a combination fails.

So my question is:

- Why can't we copy the data from the test_array to the a[]-array after the for-loop?

I appreciate any comments.

Comment: `Why can't we copy the data from the test_array to the a[]-array after the for-loop. `  All you're doing is moving the memory corruption bug around when you change the source code.  It has nothing to do with the difference between an int and an int array entry.  So the issue is that you have corrupted memory somewhere, and you need to figure out where.  So my advice to you is to make sure the bug still exists (don't hide it by doing superfluous coding changes), and fix the problem.

Comment: I don't see a reason why this shouldn't work for you. Does it fail on other gpus? It could be a bug in the implementation. If you have access to Intel HD graphics or an AMD/ATI device, it would be very useful to try it for debugging purposes. Maybe a bug needs to be filed with Nvidia? Maybe your specific device has an issue?

Comment: I agree with @PaulMcKenzie. Or put another way, it's in the "do something here" part that you left out. <g>

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie /mfa: thanks for the fast reply.
We tried to execute this on a AMD device and it worked. But we would like to run it on a Nvidia device also (without using CUDA).
 
We do have this issue on a Nvidia device (tested on the same Nvidia card at two different computers) but not on the tested AMD device. The do-part only fills the test-array with integer values after doing some checks.

Comment: maybee thats your problem? filling the "test-array" of size 2 within a loop that runs until 20 and writing values outside of the array bounds. Nvidia OpenCL error codes are not always standard conform, especially -5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I am the coworker of Sven,

We found the issue. It was less an memory problem like we thought, it was more a semantic error.

Inside of the loop we had to make use of an if statement. This if statement will not be evaluated like on a CPU we needed one thread for each branch of the if. So we had to change the local workgroup size from 1 to at least 2.
So that all threads run with the case that the if is true and all with the false statement. The wrong one will be thrown away.

This lead to an error on the NVIDIA cards, but I don't know why. We also tested an other NVIDIA card which also throws the -5(CL_OUT_OF_RESSOURCES). 
The AMD card we used worked but was more then just slow.

So thanks all for your comments with a lot of hints in it. But the solution was to set a bigger local work group to get it to work.